# what am I doing wrong? No errors

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
function showComments(wallID){
    $.ajax({
      url: "misc/showComments.php",
             type: "POST",
      data: { mode: 'ajax', wallID: wallID }, 
      success: function(msg){

      var $msg = $('#showWallCommentsFor'+wallID).find('.userWallComment');
// if it already has a comment, fade it out, add the text, then toggle it back in
if ( $msg.text().length ) {
  $msg.fadeOut('fast', function(){
    $msg.text( msg ).slideToggle(300); 
  });
} else {
  // otherwise just hide it, add the text, and then  toggle it in
  $msg.hide().text( msg ).slideToggle(300); 
}
      }
    });
}
```

msg, the response i get: ( firebug )

```
    <span class='userWallComment'>
<span style='float: left;'>
<img style='border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 44px; height: 48px; margin-right: 8px;' src='images/profilePhoto/thumbs/noPhoto_thumb.jpg'>
</span></span>
<span style='font-size: 10px; margin-bottom: 2px;'>
<a href='profil.php?id=1'>Navn navn</a> - igår kl. 01:55
</span>
<br>
DETTE ER EN TEST
<br>
<div class="clearfloat"></div>
</span>
```

It sends and execute the ajax call properly, and it have something in response, but it doesnt toggle it?

This is the div:

```
<div id="showWallCommentsFor<?php echo $displayWall["id"]; ?>" style="display: none;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The Problem

Your `if` - `else` statement has a flaw:

```
if ( $msg.text().length ) {
  //  ...
} else {
  // $msg has a length of ZERO by definition here!!!
  $msg.hide().text( msg ).slideToggle(300); 
}
```

The very first time the AJAX call is fired `#showWallCommentsFor` is empty, so it doesn't have `.userWallComment` inside it so, `$msg` will not be defined.

### The Solution

You should add text directly to the original div in your `else`, using:

```
if ( $msg.text().length ) {
  //  ...
} else {
    // otherwise just hide it, add the text, and then  toggle it in
      // You cannot use $msg here, since it has a length of 0.
      // Add text directly to the original div instead.
      // You do not need to hide the DIV first since it is already 
      // invisible.
    $('#showWallCommentsFor'+wallID).text( msg ).slideToggle(300); 
 }
```

Finally, in your `else`, there's no need to `.hide()` the `#showWall...` div, since the div is orginally invisible due to `style="display: none;"`.

Comment: @Tomalak - In my brain... alone. I meant $msg, which is why you should check $msg.text().length before proceeding. - tks for the catch.